# in java: when I fetch imaps folders multiple in one minute, i see this error: Unexpected item LIST

Tags: email, smtp, jakarta-mail, imap, pop3

- my code is

  ```
  import javax.mail.Folder;
  import javax.mail.Session;
  import javax.mail.Store;
  import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
  import java.util.Properties;


  ....
  ....

          Store store = null;
          Folder mailFolder = null;
          Properties props = System.getProperties();
          props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
          try {
              SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
              ctx.init(null, null, null);
              SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          props.setProperty("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");

          Session session2 = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
          session2.setDebug(true);
          store = session2.getStore("imaps");
          store.connect("mailtest.com", 993, "test", "test");
          mailFolder = store.getDefaultFolder();
          javax.mail.Folder[] f = mailFolder.list("*");
  ```

  debug is:

  DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea DEBUG: getProvider()
  returning
  javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun
  Microsystems, Inc] DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384 DEBUG: enable
  SASL

  - OK mailtest.com A0 CAPABILITY
  - CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE LITERAL+ MULTIAPPEND SPECIAL-USE NAMESPACE UIDPLUS QUOTA XLIST ID LOGINDISABLED AUTH=CRAM-MD5
    AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 AUTH=GSSAPI ACL RIGHTS=texkbn A0 OK CAPABILITY
    completed IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: CRAM-MD5 IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: DIGEST-MD5
    IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: GSSAPI DEBUG: protocolConnect login,
    host=mailtest.com, user=test, password= IMAP SASL DEBUG:
    Mechanisms: CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 GSSAPI IMAP SASL DEBUG: callback
    length: 2 IMAP SASL DEBUG: callback 0:
    javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback@663b1c53 IMAP SASL DEBUG:
    callback 1: javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback@32c0c194
    IMAP SASL DEBUG: SASL client CRAM-MD5 A1 AUTHENTICATE CRAM-MD5

  - PDQwMjM2ODc1MTEuMTU2NjkxNDZAd2VibWFpbC5zaGlyYXp1LmFjLmlyPg== IMAP SASL DEBUG: challenge: 4023687511.15669146@mailtest.com : IMAP SASL
    DEBUG: response: test 8127c2303f4866ee9e7e934227f10bc7 :
    c3NvdGVzdDEgODEyN2MyMzAzZjQ4NjZlZTllN2U5MzQyMjdmMTBiYzc= A2 LIST ""
    "*" A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed A2 BAD Error: Unexpected item LIST
    javax.mail.MessagingException: A2 BAD Error: Unexpected item LIST;
    nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A2 BAD Error: Unexpected item LIST
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.doCommand(IMAPFolder.java:2337)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.DefaultFolder.list(DefaultFolder.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portlet.action.NotificationPortlet.serveResource(NotificationPortlet.java:146)

Answer (score 1):

The key:

```
A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed
A2 BAD Error: Unexpected item LIST
```

The first line says you couldn't log in, for whatever reason. Because of that, the next command surprised the server. (The LIST command is only valid after *successful* login.)